# Change of PolygonCollider2D vertices by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change the position of the PolygonCollider2D vertices with a script?

Comment: Please review [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [I downvoted because this question does not show research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). Third link on Google : [How to edit PolygonCollider2D vertices IN CODE?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/624508/how-to-edit-a-polygoncollider2d-vertices-in-code.html)

Comment: @Hellium I found this example. It doesn’t work for me

Comment: And have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D-points.html)?

Comment: tried all the examples from Google already...

Answer (score 2):

Here it works

```
pc2d.points = new[]{point1, point2, point3};
pc2d.SetPath (0, new[]{ point1, point2, point3 });
```

Comment: note the critical TIP in the comments HERE:  http://answers.unity.com/answers/1116764/view.html

Answer (score 1):

The `points` member is accessible.

```cs
PolygonCollider2D p; //Just a dummy declaration. You have to actually have a MonoBehaviour set up.
p.points[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

Comment: never tried it, but `PolygonCollider2D.SetPath` looks promising aswell. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.SetPath.html

Comment: does not work
` _prefab = Instantiate (PREFAB) as GameObject; _prefab.transform.position = point1; 
pc2d = _prefab.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>(); 
pc2d.points [0] = point1; 
pc2d.points [1] = point2; 
pc2d.points [2] = point3;`

Answer (score 0):

seeing the other answers, i think this will be more complete because the other only take a part of the problem and here i will try to collect the other answer and do a complete answer:

if you want change your collider point of you own gameobject you can do:

it is giving a group of new point like the next example, in that way you will change all the point that the polygon have before at least that you want to change only a part of the paths of the collection of points that you could have for example `SetPath (0, new[]{ point1, point2, point3 });` change only the path "0" of your collider not the others paths:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class destroy_out_screen : MonoBehaviour
{
     public GameObject cameraGO; 



     void adapt_collider(){

        Vector2 point1 = new Vector2(1,1);
        Vector2 point2 = new Vector2(0,1);
        Vector2 point3 = new Vector2(0,0);
        Vector2 point4 = new Vector2(1,0);

        gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points = new[]{point1,point2,point3,point4};
    }
    void Start()
    {
        adapt_collider();
    }
}
```

of course that you will need the component in your gameobject first like this:

[image]

and about doing this:

```
p.points[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

according to the unity forum you can't do this, [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-access-polygoncollider2d-points.225560/) I give the link where i found

in the end you will get this:

[image]

depending of the order that you give to the points to the collider.